# Call class B from class A and inherit class A properties?

Tags: php, inheritance

I was wondering if such a combination is possible.

classA.php

```
class A
{
    public $one = "one";

    function start() {

        $this->one = "seven";

        include "classB.php";
        $two = new B;
        print_r(get_defined_vars());
    }
}
```

classB.php

```
class B extends A
{
    public $two = "two";

    function __construct() {
        echo($this->one);
    }
}
```

and finally index.php

```
include "classA.php";
$A = new A;
$A->start();
```

When I run index.php, I get the following:

```
Array
(
    [one] => seven
    [B] => B Object
        (
            [two] => two
            [one] => one
        )
    )
```

Is there a way to make class B use updated variables? Or do I have to just split the code into two files and use it separately? That way it works at least... But I don't like my code being outside classes and I try to minimize the use of global scope...

Comment: BTW: I know of __construct(), I wrote the code without __construct so that __construct() wouldn't be called at all.

Comment: You really should read a bit more about inheritance actually works.... if class B extends class A, then you should be instantiating class B.... but not embedding the code for class B in the middle of class A via include.... that isn't inheritance at all

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: sectus, I want to have this in the end: Array ( [one] => seven [B] => B Object ( [two] => two [one] => seven ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to include class b into class a.

Simply use class B extend A, thats all.

In your output you created a new object B which extends class A, but this B object is a new instance with no relation to the parent class.

Try this:

```
class A {
  public $propA = 'Property of A class';
}

class B extends A {
  public $propB = 'Property of B class';
}

$obj = new B();

echo $obj->propA; // returns "Property of A class"
echo $obj->propB; // returns "Property of B class"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use statics. Its a terrible practice, but:

```
class A
{
    public static $one = "one";

    function start()
    {

        $one = "seven";

        $two = new B;
        print_r(get_defined_vars());
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public $two = "two";

    function __construct() {
        echo($this::$one);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, php.net documentation is a bit scarce. That's why we have Stackoverflow, for which I'm grateful. Thanx for the tip, I realized it now. Learning something new every day.

To the point. The code in index.php should have looked like this:

```
include "classA.php";
include "classB.php";

$B = new B;
print_r(get_defined_vars());

$B->start();
print_r(get_defined_vars());
```

Now it outputs exactly what I need:

```
[B] => B Object ( [two] => two [one] => one ) // before the change
[B] => B Object ( [two] => two [one] => seven ) // after the change
```